# Why doesn't top: 0 work on absolutely-positioned elements relative to body?

Tags: html, css, css-position, specifications

You can see in the code below that the `h1` pushes down the body and the absolutely-positioned block `.absolute` does not stick to the top. But you also can see that the same block is stuck to the top of its parent `.wrapper`. Why?

I'm not asking how to do that trick; I know how, e.g. padding instead margin to h1, or clearfix to parent and so on.

I'm interested in only one thing: why `h1`'s margin pushes down the `body`, but is not pushing down `.wrapper`?

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: silver;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.wrapper > .absolute {
  background-color: darkcyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="absolute"></div>
<h1>Some title</h1>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="absolute"></div>
  <h1>Some title</h1>
</div>
```

OK, I'll try to be more clear. If you click on the link below, you can see my JSFiddle. There is `background-color: silver` in the `body` tag. When I look in the code inspector, I see that the body tag begins slightly lower due to the h1 margin. But `background-color` begins at the top. This means that the code inspector is lying to me, and body begins from top. But why, then, does an absolutely-positioned element that's a direct child of `body` not start at the top?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86yk24zh/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS margin pushing the body element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742720/css-margin-pushing-the-body-element)

Comment: @CroaToa OK I got your answer, see my post.

Comment: Not a duplicate - that question doesn't involve any absolutely positioned elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does making the body tag's style "position: relative" cause an absolute-positioned div start lower?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692695/why-does-making-the-body-tags-style-position-relative-cause-an-absolute-posi)

Comment: @DonRhummy, as I commented in your post, yes, the questions are similar and probably duplicates. But the answers are an ocean apart. Your question didn't receive any quality answers. In fact, [one of the answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25697283/3597276) to your question points this out. This question, however, received a clear and complete explanation, plus other valuable insights. Hence, it wouldn't be helpful to users to re-direct this question to yours.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned, the containing block of the top-level absolutely positioned element is `body`, as `body` is relatively positioned. When the margin of the `h1` [collapses](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) with that of `body`, this causes the margin to affect `body`, and in turn the absolutely positioned element that it contains. Conversely, if `body` *wasn't* relatively positioned, the absolutely positioned element would be anchored to the initial containing block, and stick to the top of the viewport unaffected by any effective margins on `body` (because `body` is no longer its containing block).

As to why the silver background bleeds beyond the `body` element, that's [by design](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#special-backgrounds):

> **3.11.1. The Canvas Background and the Root Element**
>
> The background of the root element becomes the background of the canvas and its background painting area extends to cover the entire canvas. However, any images are sized and positioned relative to the root element as if they were painted for that element alone. (In other words, the background positioning area is determined as for the root element.) The root element does not paint this background again, i.e., the used value of its background is transparent.
>
> **3.11.2. The Canvas Background and the HTML <body> Element**
>
> For documents whose root element is an HTML `HTML` element or an XHTML `html` element: if the computed value of ‘background-image’ on the root element is ‘none’ and its ‘background-color’ is ‘transparent’, user agents must instead propagate the computed values of the background properties from that element's first HTML `BODY` or XHTML `body` child element. The used values of that BODY element's background properties are their initial values, and the propagated values are treated as if they were specified on the root element. It is recommended that authors of HTML documents specify the canvas background for the `BODY` element rather than the `HTML` element.

The root element's default background color is always `transparent`, so setting a background color on the `html` element prevents the silver background from bleeding out of the `body` element (and you'll see that the inspector is in fact not lying to you):

```css
html {
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: silver;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.wrapper > .absolute {
  background-color: darkcyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="absolute"></div>
<h1>Some title</h1>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="absolute"></div>
  <h1>Some title</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: @Quantastical: I just woke up and holy upvotes Batman... this must have made hot network questions or something. Who said no one cares?

Comment: @BoltClock The votes are from the committee tasked with illustrating how much no one cares <3

Answer (score 8):

It's because [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#collapsing-margins). How to disable it, you could read in some articles/answers, for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718634/how-to-disable-margin-collapsing).
You are using `overflow: hidden` for `.wrapper`, and it disables collapsing margins for this block. From [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#collapsing-margins):

> Margins of a box with ‘overflow’ other than ‘visible’ do not collapse with its children's margins.

But it seems like `overflow: hidden` doesn't work for `<body>`, because if I set
`height: 0`/`max-height: 0` it doesn't work too:

```css
body {
    height: 0;
    max-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>Some test text</div>
```

I think it's because (from [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#propdef-overflow)):

> UAs must apply the 'overflow' property set on the root element to the viewport. When the root element is an HTML "HTML" element or an XHTML "html" element, and that element has an HTML "BODY" element or an XHTML "body" element as a child, user agents must instead apply the 'overflow' property from the first such child element to the viewport, if the value on the root element is 'visible'.

That's why margins between `<body>` and first `<h1>` collapse (from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)):

> **Parent and first/last child**
>   If there is no border, padding, inline content, or *clearance* to separate the `margin-top` of a block with the `margin-top` of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, *height*, *min-height*, or *max-height* to separate the `margin-bottom` of a block with the `margin-bottom` of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

That's why margins between `<html>` and `<body>` don't collapse (from [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#collapsing-margins)):

> Margins of the root element's box do not collapse.

I also noticed that if `<html>` has default `background-color` and `<body>` has specified `background-color` + `margin`, the background color fills the entire space of `<html>`, for example:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

But if you set `background-color` to `<html>`, it works like a normal block, for example:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

html {
    background-color: red;
}

body {
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

I summary, I recommend you to use [other approaches to disable collapsing margins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718634/how-to-disable-margin-collapsing), or add another wrapper for `<body>`, for example:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.body-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: silver;
}

.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: darkblue;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.wrapper > .absolute {
    background-color: darkcyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-wrapper">
    <div class="absolute"></div>
    <h1>Some title</h1>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="absolute"></div>
        <h1>Some title</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

This is another instance of the phenomenon known as [`margin-collapsing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

I'll try to explain what is happening:

When you move `div.absolute` with position absolute, it pulls it out of the flow of the content. This causes the first `h1` to act as the first-child of its parent, which is `body` in this case.

The `h1`'s margin then gets collapsed *outside* the body, due to margin-collapsing. That is why `top: 0;` is not in the upper-left of the viewport. It is in the upper left of the `body`.

If you need to get this to work, then add a `html {position: relative; overflow: hidden:}`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answer, but why  body's `background-color` from top? And why `padding: 1px` fixes that?

Comment: I can't answer that with any certainty. All I know is margin-collapsing is stupid, in my opinion. If you want to make the color outside the body, then add `html {background: white;}`

Comment: See my reply and the `margin-collapsing` of webkit is `collapse` by default. http://help.dottoro.com/lcptobdv.php

Comment: Collapsing margins is not stupid. Without it, adjacent paragraphs would have twice the spacing between then. Then, if you reduced the margin to compensate, you would have to add something to increase margin when you wanted spacing to other non-paragraphs. This would apply to all elements.

Comment: @Rob, Does collapsing margins explain why `top: 0` works in `.wrapper` (the yellow box), but not in `body`? Does it explain why the gray background of `body` covers the entire viewport, but the `top: 0`-aligned box starts lower? If so, an explanation would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Stupid or not the `margin-collapsing` isn't the problem, I get the same problem with the setting on `-webkit-margin-after-collapse: collapse` and `-webkit-margin-before-collapse:collapse` on  body and html

Comment: @Michael_B Ugh. I've already moved on but add a border to .wrapper and see what happens differently. Don't know if it applies cause I've changed gears.

Comment: @Rob Ugh, Michael_B moved on before you did. I have the answer but no cares, so I'll move on as well.

Comment: Since y'all have moved on, [don't mind if I do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33594788/why-doesnt-top-0-work-on-absolutely-positioned-element-relative-to-body/33597266#33597266)...

Answer (score 3):

This is interesting behavior with little documentation to be found online (at least on a basic search).

I'll start by saying I don't know the reason why the absolutely positioned box doesn't align to the corner of `body`, as it would be expected to do. But here are a few observations:

1. The expected positioning works on IE11. The gap exists in Chrome and FF.
2. If you remove `position: relative` from `body`, the expected positioning works (as tested in Chrome, FF & IE11). [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/86yk24zh/6/)
3. If you apply just 1px `padding` to `body`, it also works cross-browser.  [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/86yk24zh/5/)
4. If you add a border to `body`, it also works. [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/86yk24zh/4/)

---

**UPDATE**

As a quick addendum to [@BoltClock's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33597266/3597276), this problem could have been easily illustrated and understood by just adding a background color to the root element in the original code...

```
html { background-color: red; }
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/86yk24zh/11/)

... and by removing the default margin on the `h1`:

```
h1 { margin: 0; }
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/86yk24zh/12/)

Comment: 2. When I remove `position: relative` from `body` it means, that absolute element takes its values from browser window, because it hasn't relative parent. Therefore it looks good. Interesting behavior:) Left to learn what did padding: 1px in this situation)

Comment: The reason adding the border "fixes" it is due to collapsing margins as explained in the other answer by @Quantastical

Comment: No it isn't `-webkit-margin-collapse: collapse` is already set. It's `background-origin` see my solution.

Comment: "If a positioned ancestor doesn't exist, then body is used." No, the initial containing block is used - and the initial containing block is at a higher level than body (above the root element, in fact). Relative positioning on body isn't redundant. IE's behavior is incorrect. I posted an answer btw.

Comment: @BoltClock, I knew when I wrote `body` instead of *initial containing block* I was leaving myself open for a correction, but I said it because I suspected it was true. I guess I was wrong. I appreciate the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by `h1` having a default margin, which is keeping the `body` apart from `h1` and its sibling `.absolute`.

So all you have to do is reset the margin in `h1`, like you did for `body`:

#### snippet with every margin resetted

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: silver;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
 /*if you want to see full text, put this into the flow*/   
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: darkblue;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.wrapper > .absolute {
  background-color: darkcyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="absolute"></div>
<h1>Some title</h1>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="absolute"></div>
  <h1>Some title</h1>
</div>
```

---

#### snippet with every no margin resetted

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  /* margin: 0; */
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: silver;
}
h1 {
  /* margin: 0; */
  /*if you want to see full text, put this into the flow*/
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: darkblue;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.wrapper > .absolute {
  background-color: darkcyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="absolute"></div>
<h1>Some title</h1>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="absolute"></div>
  <h1>Some title</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: So why doesn't the problem exist in `.wrapper`?

Comment: I did not set downvote. The question  about why the box doesn't align to the top left corner of body. Why code inspector show me that `body` begins lower, but background-color from top?